# API in my backend should get data from the User_Subscription table Using the user_ID but it return data by ID

Tags: java, spring-boot

This API in my backend should get data from the `User_Subscription` table using the `user_ID`, but when I test it, it says forbidden. When I try to replace the `user_ID` with the ID of the record in the database it returns the correct data. What’s wrong? How can I make it return data from the `user_ID`? Only save endpoint works the way it should.

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/userSubPlan")
public class UserSubscriptionController {
    private final UserSubscriptionService userSubscriptionPlanService;
    private final UserSubscriptionService userSubscriptionService;

    @PostMapping("/{user_id}/{subscription_plan_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> AddSubPlan(@PathVariable Long user_id, @PathVariable Long subscription_plan_id) {

        try {
            userSubscriptionPlanService.AddSubPlan(user_id,subscription_plan_id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();// Return HTTP 400 Bad Request
        }}

    @GetMapping("/{user_id}/SubID")
    public Long getUserId(@PathVariable("user_id") Long userId) {

            Long subscriptionId = userSubscriptionService.getSubscriptionId(userId);
            if (subscriptionId != null) {
                return subscriptionId;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Subscription not found for user with ID: " + userId);
            }
    }


    @GetMapping("/{user_id}/SubEndDate")
    public ResponseEntity<Timestamp> getEndDate(@PathVariable("user_id") Long userID) {
        try {
            Timestamp endDate = userSubscriptionService.getSubscriptionEndDate(userID);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(endDate);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();// Return HTTP 400 Bad Request
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/{user_id}/SubStartDate")
    public ResponseEntity<Timestamp> getStartDate(@PathVariable("user_id") Long userID) {
        try {
            Timestamp StartDate = userSubscriptionService.getSubscriptionStartDate(userID);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(StartDate);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();// Return HTTP 400 Bad Request
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/{user_id}/SubPrice")
    public ResponseEntity<Double> getPrice(@PathVariable("user_id") Long userID) {
        try {
            Double Price = userSubscriptionService.getSubscriptionPrice(userID);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(Price);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();// Return HTTP 400 Bad Request
        }
    }



    }
```

The service:

```
public class UserSubscriptionService {
    private final UserSubscriptionJpaRepo userSubscriptionJpaRepo;
    private final UserJpaRepo userJpaRepo;
    private final SubscriptionPlanJpaRepo subscriptionPlanJpaRepo;

    public void AddSubPlan(Long userId, Long subscriptionPlanId) {
        UserSubscriptionDBO userSubPlan = new UserSubscriptionDBO();
        User user = userJpaRepo.findById(userId).orElse(null);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User not Created");
        }
        userSubPlan.setUserDBO(user);
        SubscriptionPlanDBO subPlan = subscriptionPlanJpaRepo.findById(subscriptionPlanId).orElse(null);
        if (subPlan == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Subscription Plan not found");
        }
        userSubPlan.setSubscriptionPlanDBO(subPlan);
        Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        userSubPlan.setSubscriptionStartDate(currentTimestamp);

        if (subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 1 || subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 4 || subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 7) {
            userSubPlan.setSubscriptionEndDate(calculateSubscriptionEndDateDay(userSubPlan));
            userSubscriptionJpaRepo.save(userSubPlan);
        }
        if (subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 2 || subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 5 || subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 8) {
            userSubPlan.setSubscriptionEndDate(calculateSubscriptionEndDateWeeks(userSubPlan));
            userSubscriptionJpaRepo.save(userSubPlan);
        }
        if (subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 3 || subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 6 || subPlan.getSubscriptionPlanID() == 9) {
            userSubPlan.setSubscriptionEndDate(calculateSubscriptionEndDate(userSubPlan));
            userSubscriptionJpaRepo.save(userSubPlan);
        }
        // userSubPlan.setSubscriptionEndDate(calculateSubscriptionEndDate(userSubPlan));
      //  userSubscriptionJpaRepo.save(userSubPlan);
    }


    private Timestamp calculateSubscriptionEndDate(UserSubscriptionDBO userSubPlan) {
        LocalDateTime startDate = userSubPlan.getSubscriptionStartDate().toLocalDateTime();
        int monthsToAdd = userSubPlan.getSubscriptionPlanDBO().getDuration();

        LocalDateTime endDate = startDate.plusMonths(monthsToAdd);

        return Timestamp.valueOf(endDate);
    }

    public Long getSubscriptionId(Long userId) {
        User user = userJpaRepo.findById(userId).orElse(null);
        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }
        UserSubscriptionDBO userSubPlan = userSubscriptionJpaRepo.findById(userId).orElse(null);

        if (userSubPlan == null) { return null;}
        else return userSubPlan.getSubscriptionPlanDBO().getSubscriptionPlanID();
    }



    public Timestamp getSubscriptionEndDate(Long userId) {
        User user = userJpaRepo.findById(userId).orElse(null);
        UserSubscriptionDBO userSubPlan = userSubscriptionJpaRepo.findById(userId).orElse(null);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("user not found");
        }
        else return userSubPlan.getSubscriptionEndDate();
    }

    public Timestamp getSubscriptionStartDate(Long userId) {
        User user = userJpaRepo.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("User not found for user ID: " + userId));

        UserSubscriptionDBO userSubPlan = userSubscriptionJpaRepo.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("User subscription not found for user ID: " + userId));

        return userSubPlan.getSubscriptionStartDate();
    }



    public Double getSubscriptionPrice(Long userId) {
        User user = userJpaRepo.findById(userId).orElse(null);
        UserSubscriptionDBO userSubPlan = userSubscriptionJpaRepo.findById(userId).orElse(null);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User not found");
        }

        if (userSubPlan == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User subscription not found");
        }

        return userSubPlan.getSubscriptionPlanDBO().getPrice();
    }



    private Timestamp calculateSubscriptionEndDateDay(UserSubscriptionDBO userSubPlan) {
        LocalDateTime startDate = userSubPlan.getSubscriptionStartDate().toLocalDateTime();
        int DaysToAdd = userSubPlan.getSubscriptionPlanDBO().getDuration();

        LocalDateTime endDate = startDate.plusDays(DaysToAdd);

        return Timestamp.valueOf(endDate);

    }

    private Timestamp calculateSubscriptionEndDateWeeks(UserSubscriptionDBO userSubPlan) {
        LocalDateTime startDate = userSubPlan.getSubscriptionStartDate().toLocalDateTime();
        int weeksToAdd = userSubPlan.getSubscriptionPlanDBO().getDuration();

        LocalDateTime endDate = startDate.plusWeeks(weeksToAdd);

        return Timestamp.valueOf(endDate);
    }
}
```

The DBO:

```
public class UserSubscriptionDBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    //foreign key with the user table
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User userDBO;

    @Column(name = "subscription_start_date" )
    private Timestamp subscriptionStartDate;

    @Column(name = "subscription_end_date" )
    private Timestamp subscriptionEndDate;

    //foreign key with the user table
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_plan_id")
    private SubscriptionPlanDBO subscriptionPlanDBO;

    public UserSubscriptionDBO(Long id, User userDBO, Timestamp subscriptionStartDate,  SubscriptionPlanDBO subscriptionPlanDBO) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userDBO = userDBO;
        this.subscriptionStartDate = subscriptionStartDate;
        this.subscriptionPlanDBO = subscriptionPlanDBO;

        // Calculate the subscription start date (assuming it's the current date)
        this.subscriptionStartDate = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay());

    }

    private Timestamp calculateSubscriptionEndDate(Timestamp durationMonths) {
        LocalDate startDate = subscriptionStartDate.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();

        // Convert durationMonths to a number of months
        int monthsToAdd = durationMonths.toLocalDateTime().getMonthValue();

        // Calculate the end date by adding months to the start date
        LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusMonths(monthsToAdd);

        return Timestamp.valueOf(endDate.atStartOfDay());
    }

}
```

When I test this API http://localhost:8081/api/v1/userSubPlan/304/SubEndDate IN POSTMAN it returns "Not Found" even though there is a record for the user with the id; 304 but when I test it using the record ID it returns the `EndDate`.